# Temperature stabilizer problem

Tags: bathroom, air-conditioning, temperature

In my 1 room + bathroom apartment in Germany, these mechanisms (searching Google by them didn't name them) exist:

[image]

in bathroom, and in the room, there is this:

[image]

When I am taking a (long?) shower, these mechanisms seem to communicate and exchange air, in order to balance the temperature between the room and the WC, I guess.

The problem is that the mechanism in the room is above the desk with my laptop, and outputs cold air, making it dangerous to sit in the desk just after the shower, since I might get cold. I have to wait ~10mins, and the mechanism stops.

Can I minimize the time the mechanism emits air in this specific scenario?

If yes, how? The key parameter in this, seems to be the door of the bathroom. Leave it open after exiting the bathroom, or close it?

My few experiments show that closing the door makes the mechanism stop earlier, I think... However, this contradicts my assumption that the mechanism exchange air (since leaving the door open should help in balancing the temperature)..

---

<sub>Hello to the community! I read the Help Center, and it seems that my question is OK for here-if not, please let me know!</sub>

Comment: That looks like a mini split system, each unit should have a zone control but without more anything else would be a guess.

Comment: @EdBeal, thanks for identifying these mechanisms! Hmmm, if I can improve my answer, please, let me know! The Help Center mentioned images and location.

Comment: Can you find the model numbers? They are usually inside the cover next to a filter element that needs to be changed or cleaned. Do you have a remote control to program the set points or thermostats? These are things that will help us understand your system and provide real answers, the photos did help so you have started off well with your question.

Comment: I searched @EdBeal, no.. The only information I have is that the one in the bathroom is branded as Helios (sun in Greek). Nothing else that I know (so that means that the community is not able to help, thus I should delete my question?). This is a rent apartment.

Comment: Give it some time there are many folks a around the world, some that know that unit may be online in a few hours, I have seen questions with less info get awesome answers by a person that had the same unit.

Comment: the two devices may be separate .... the top one appear to be just a fan .... google `helios fan` to get this ... https://www.badshop-web.de/AIRING-NEED/Helios-blower-units-to-2008/helios-small-fan-m1-100-p-with-motion-detector-6174.html ...... the bottom one may be just an air conditioner ..... opening the door to the steamy bathroom may raise the temperature in the living room enough to make the AC kick in

Comment: That would explain my impression that keeping the door closed will minimize the cold air emission in the room, thanks @jsotola!

Comment: if that is the actual case, then  why don't  you simply turn off the air conditioner

Comment: I didn't thought of that @jsotola, because I didn't have a remote control. There is a switch though (I saw it first when Ed Beal asked for more details, and now that you mentioned it), which has the open/close circuit signs... I will try that next time, thanks!

Comment: Setting the switch on or off doesn't affect the emission of cold air, it seems that the emission in the room is connected to when the mechanism in the bathroom operates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that it is an Air Conditioner being used as a dehumidifier to prevent the buildup of moisture in your WC. That is why you are feeling a cold air stream on the other side. Modifying it would likely be cause for eviction as it could allow mold growth in the wet areas. I would look into fabricating some sort of deflector to keep the air stream from coming right down onto your desk. Cardboard and duct tape would suffice, just don't actually block the air flow, all you need do is direct it elsewhere.

Comment: I see your point, that must be it! Do you think that leaving the door open could help demoisturise the bathroom sooner than closing it, after I am done with my shower?

Comment: Probably, yes. Anything that exchanges air faster will help. I take it your shower area does not have a vent to the outside?